# Databricks cost monitoring for clusters coming from the same pool

Tags: cluster-computing, databricks, azure-databricks, pool, tagging

We have a pool with idle instances for which we want to do some cost monitoring. There are idle instances running on the pool, so we want to link the clusters used internally by different teams to the same pool since the idle instances are running anyway.

However, cluster tags are not propagated to the cloud instances (VMs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/usage-detail-tags-azure), so we are not able to monitor the costs for separate clusters. Hence, we cannot propagate the full databricks cost to the internal teams in our organization that are using the databricks workspace.

How should we set up databricks in order to be able to propagate costs to the correct internal team. Note that we do not want to use separate pools, since this will result in having idle instances in each pool which will increase the costs of the VM usage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, right now it's not possible out of box using the built-in tooling.

But Databricks Labs recently published the new project called [Overwatch](https://github.com/databrickslabs/overwatch/) that allows to collect information from multiple data sources - diagnostic logs, Events API, cluster logs, etc., process it and make it available for consumption - approximate costs analysis, performance optimization, etc.  The big advantage of this tool is that can get very granular details, down to the individual Spark jobs/stages/tasks.  For example, you can calculate the approximate costs per user, or notebook, or cluster, or job, ...

P.S. please note that Databricks Labs projects are not a part of official product, so there are no SLAs in case of problems, but there is a team who are working on that tool, trying to make fixes as fast as possible.